# Apache virtual server and hardcoded mysql connectors using ip addresses

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

xampp distribution 5.6.15 with Apache 2.4.17 MariaDB 10.1.10 running on w7-64,

I've recreated a copy of a production website on my local box using virtual hosting.  Works great except for the hard coded mysql connectors distributed all about the code.

Modifying these files is not an option at this time.  Question is, is there a way to setup Apache, or mysql, to allow these connections to work?

Here's an example (older technology):

```
mysql_connect('123.123.123.123', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

The mysql database is running outside of this xampp port. It is an identical mysql/MariaDB release. The database connects when the host is properly named.

Thank you.  (please leave the php tag - these guys know a lot.)

MORE INFO - Edit

I've modified two files trying to remap the ip address.

\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
and
\xampp2\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

With host names it worked find. Here are the additional entries I made. If you can think of a permutation, I've probably tried it. I'm wonder now it this isn't some mysql config problem. Again, take away the ip address, use a name, and everything is fine: (it's the entries with the ip addresses that fail. After any change in either of these two files, I cycled Apache and flushed the dns. Error message from connect attempt is:

mysql_connect(): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host

======================================================================

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs"
ServerName www.production.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs"
ServerName www.production.com
</VirtualHost>
```

====================================================================

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 www.mspfound.com # second server
123.123.123.123 localhost
```

or

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 www.mspfound.com # second server
123.123.123.123 www.mspfound.com
```

Comment: Hm, add this IP address to your local box?

Answer (score 0):

You can not override an ip address locally, what you can do is reroute connections through a proxy server and/or some iptables changes, but that's not really my area, another idea would be setting up a local or virtual network where the mysql server can use the same ip as the existing production server,I usually did this using couple of virtual boxes connected to the same virtual network and using the same subnet as the server in question.

but that's all quick fixing and patching, what you should really be doing (I hope you've done it already, it's been 3 months!) is to replace all ip addresses in code with either a config variable that can be changed centrally or a virtual host name that can be changed in your hosts file, also you probably need to replace the deprecated mysql_* functions.

Best of luck.